# Where does say in ECMAScript that resolved promise has [[PromiseResult]] equal to object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to match the workings of a promise's `resolve` function against the corresponding procedure in the ECMAScript specification. More specifically, I am looking for the specification in the case the resolve function is called with an object value.

Take these examples:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("hello");
});
new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({a: 100});
});
```

There is one difference between these two promises: the type of value passed to the `resolve` function.

Here is the procedure for the resolve function from the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions):

> 1. Let *F* be the active function object.
> 2. Assert: *F* has a [[Promise]] internal slot whose value is an Object.
> 3. Let *promise* be *F*.[[Promise]].
> 4. Let *alreadyResolved* be *F*.[[AlreadyResolved]].
> 5. If *alreadyResolved*.[[Value]] is **true**, return **undefined**.
> 6. Set *alreadyResolved*.[[Value]] to **true**.
> 7. If SameValue(*resolution*, *promise*) is **true**, then
>
>    a. Let *selfResolutionError* be a newly created **TypeError** object.
>
>    b. Return RejectPromise(*promise*, *selfResolutionError*).
> 8. If Type(resolution) is not Object, then
>
>    a. Return FulfillPromise(*promise*, *resolution*).
> 9. Let *then* be Get(*resolution*, **"then"**).
> 10. If *then* is an abrupt completion, then
>
>     a. Return RejectPromise(*promise*, *then*.[[Value]]).
> 11. Let *thenAction* be *then*.[[Value]].
> 12. If IsCallable(*thenAction*) is **false**, then
>
>     a. Return FulfillPromise(*promise*, *resolution*).
> 13. Let *thenJobCallback* be HostMakeJobCallback(*thenAction*).
> 14. Let *job* be NewPromiseResolveThenableJob(*promise*, *resolution*, *thenJobCallback*).
> 15. Perform HostEnqueuePromiseJob(*job*.[[Job]], *job*.[[Realm]]).
> 16. Return **undefined**.

I cannot pinpoint where the case is treated that has an object as argument without a `then` property.

Comment: 12a?  thenAction isn't callable if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? The difference between the two examples is that in one case you’re resolving with a string, in the other one you’re resolving with an object. How is that related to an “object but that one has not a property `then`”?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey wait, you say about 12a but for that we need to have value on step 11. By my calculations then.[[Value]] is equal to undefined, because we did not find prop "then" on step 9

Comment: Yes, so thenValue is undefined, so it is not callable.  `IsCallable` would be false

Comment: @SebastianSimon it's pretty simple. Just look at step 8. As you could see it is case for non-object argument for resolve function. But yet on step 9 we see that algorithm tries to get property "then" from resolve's argument.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey there you go, so you are agree with me, okay. Let's look further. Open `FulfillPromise(promise, resolution)` and see what does step 3: `Set promise.[[PromiseResult]] to value`. Okay do you remember what value we have? It's undefined. But we passed into resolve `{a: 100}`. What would you say on that?

Comment: No, `resolution` is `{a: 100}` and  is passed to `FulfillPromise`, and that is the value it uses

Comment: @GarrGodfrey you've destroyed me, I've not slept all night :) Seems I need to delete my topic. Thx for your help and help of others.

Comment: Sounds like your confusion comes from `Let thenAction be then.[[Value]]`, even if `then` is of type `undefined`, it still does have a `.[[Value]]` internal slot: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-attributes

Comment: @Kaiido it can't has `[[Value]]` because `undefined` is not property. In other case and I think in this case it's a `Completion Record`, is not it?

Comment: You're right, but completion records too have a [[Value]] https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-completion-record-specification-type

Comment: @Kaiido sure, that is what I call  `Completion Record` https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-completion-record-specification-type
Am I not right?

Comment: Yes, yes you are right, but only in the second part of your comment. Here `Get(resolution, "then")` will call your Object's internal [[Get]] which will indeed return a completion record, of type "normal", with an internal [[Value]] slot which itself will evaluate to `undefined`. So yes, `thenAction` is a Completion Record, but it does have a [[Value]] internal slot, which will make `IsCallable()` return false.

Comment: @Kaiido I've checked Get method again and it all time returns the `Completion Records`. So in the resolve function `[[Value]]` it's a field of `Completion Record` 24/7 hehe

Comment: Ok... but that doesn't change a thing in the current case that it's a Completion Record or a simple property value, it has a [[Value]] internal slot, it can pass the step 11, and it will exit at step 12 because its [[Value]] internal slot is not callable.

Comment: @Kaiido of course, and I am agree with you completely.
P.S About my question with event loop title, later I want to ask some question, if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 9 gets the `then` property

> 9. Let *then* be Get(*resolution*, **"then"**).

There are mainly four outcomes possible:

1. `then` is not a property of the object, so *then* (the variable) represents a completion record with [[Value]] `undefined`
2. `then` is a property of the object, but evaluating it produces an exception (e.g. it is a getter, and the getter runs into an exception). *then* is then a so-called *abrupt completion*.
3. `then` is a property of the object, but it is not a function
4. `then` is a property of the object, and it is a function.

Step 10 checks for one of these outcomes:

> 10. If *then* is an abrupt completion, then
>             a. Return RejectPromise(*promise*, *then*.[[Value]]).

Here is a snippet that makes `10.a` happen:

```js
let obj = {
    get then() {
        throw "sorry";
    }
};

new Promise(resolve => resolve(obj))
   .catch((err) => console.log("rejected with ", err))
```

This represents the case where `then` is not necessarily intended to evaluate as a function (it is a getter, so code must execute to determine that), but accessing it makes it impossible to know whether it would be a function or not, since it produces an exception. The specification mentions the execution of the getter in [[[Get]]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver)

Step 11 is a simple assignment of the `[[Value]]` field of the retrieved completion record (note that there are also other fields, like `[[Type]]`)

> 11. Let *thenAction* be *then*.[[Value]].

Step 12 checks whether this value is a function:

> 12. If IsCallable(*thenAction*) is **false**, then
>             a. Return FulfillPromise(*promise*, *resolution*).

If not a function, the main promise is fulfilled with that object as value.

The remaining steps deal with the case where *then* is a function.